# How to get list of child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

Below, I have attached an image with some console output. What I would like to do is, grab all the numbered nodes (so, `0` and `1`, but there could be more or less), and put them into an array (like `[0, 1]`).

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.toArray()](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/).

```
var listOfNodes = $list.toArray();
```

**EDIT:** As was pointed out by [SterlingArcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774078/sterling-archer), there's a better option in ES6 in the form of [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
var listOfNodes = Array.from($list);
```

Comment: ES6 is better! [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: @SterlingArcher Awesome! I didn't know that was a part of ES6. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Learning is fun :D Add that link to your answer and you got a +1 from me sir

Comment: And for us lowly folk still supporting ES5: `[].slice.call($list)`

Comment: `[...nodeList]` also exists, and I think is a little cleaner looking.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I just realized I needed something more...is it possible to get the `className` for each item in the array?

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby Sure, you could use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for one. `var listOfClassNames = listOfNodes.map(function(node) { return node.className; })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for-loop
To go through these arrays just don't use forEach, with that you will go through every property but you want the numbers only

Jquery uses a combination of arrays and associative array (objects in Javascript)

So it has auto incremented keys and words as keys

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associated arrays, those are objects.